# Private property implementation from an interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to give a property, which is implemented from an interface, private access modifier, but the compiler refuses to do that. it accepts that apparently only when I define the property with its full name (including the father interface), could some one explain me that behaviour and if there is any **better solution or workaround** that?

Example:

The compiler accepts this:

```
public interface IResourcePolicy
{
   string Version { get; }
}
public class ResourcePolicy : IResourcePolicy
{
   public string Version { get; }
}
```

And the compiler accepts this:

```
public interface IResourcePolicy
{
   string Version { get; }
}
public class ResourcePolicy : IResourcePolicy
{
   string IResourcePolicy.Version { get; }
}
```

But it does **not** accept this:

```
public interface IResourcePolicy
{
   string Version { get; }
}
public class ResourcePolicy : IResourcePolicy
{
   string Version { get; }
}
```

Comment: An interface says 'The following methods (including properties) are *publically* accessible'. Implementing the interface with private methods and properties does not make any sense.

Comment: It is called 'explicit interface implementation' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx